# Running time for algorithm to compute the minimum size dominating set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm trying to write an algorithm to compute a minimum size dominating set of an undirected graph G(V,E).

I think the following works:
1) Sort vertices by number of edges (descending)
2) Add the first vertex to the set D (which will be the dominating set output)
3) Delete all vertices connected to D by one edge
4) Add the next vertex
and then repeat until you run out of vertices.

I was wondering what the running time of this would be?

Comment: You can run this algorithm in $O(nlgn)$.  Hint: All you need is a smart way to do  (3).

Comment: Or $O(n+m)$.  By the way, the algorithm won't give you a minimum size dominating set.

Comment: Yeah. There's a nice way to do sort in this instance! p.s I forgot the $m$ factor in complexity. It's actually  $O(nlgn +m)$ but,yeah,  @PålGD's solution is better

Comment: Why won't it give me a minimum size dominating set?

Comment: Why would it give a minimum dominating set? The onus of proof is on you.